# ng-style does not work with min and ng-model is negative

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

ng-style condition `detail.Amount < 0` does not work with `min=0` if saved value of the `ng-model="detail.Amount"` is negative.

```
<input type="number" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="form-control" title="Amount" ng-model="detail.Amount" ng-style="detail.Amount < 0 && {'border':'1px solid red'}" />
```

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you create a working snippet ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha I tried it in codepen and it worked. Thanks I think my problem was I was an older version of angularjs. :)

Comment: @klent you sure it works without removing `min` property ? If you have `min` attribute angular removes that property from the scope if the value is less than `min`.

Comment: @PrakashKandel It works with min :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using **AngularJS v1.6.5** so when I changed it to the latest version **AngularJS v1.7.7** it worked.

In codepen it works even if I use the older version but I'm using asp-net so I think it was a compatibility issue.